# Find the Taylor Polynomial of $\frac{1}{1+ x}$ conflicting solution to answer given from book

Tags: calculus, solution-verification, taylor-expansion

Working on a question from *Spivak's Calculus 2nd ed* pg. 427 that asked me to find the Taylor polynomial of $f(x) = \frac{1}{1+ x}$ for degree $n$ at $0$.

First observing that $f(x) = \frac{1}{1+ x}$ can be rewritten as $f(x) = (1 + x)^{-1}$ and doing some rough work, I worked out that the formula for the coefficients should be:

$$f^{(k)}(x) = (-1)^{k}k!(x+1)^{-1-k}$$

From this I went on to state that the Taylor polynomial for $f(x) = \frac{1}{1+ x}$ should be:

$$P_{n,0,f}(x) = \sum_{k = 0}^{n} = (-1)^{k}k!x^{k}$$

But in the solution manual the answer is given as:

$$ \sum_{k = 0}^{n} = (-1)^{k}x^{k}$$

I think their solution is wrong just based on the method of finding coefficients for the Taylor polynomial. But perhaps I missed something in my construction. What is the thoughts of the forum ?

Comment: you forgot to divide on $k!$ as you should in the taylor expansion. Where the general term should read $$\frac{f^{(k)}(a)}{k!}(x-a)^k$$

Comment: Yes!!...that's what was missing....it's because I was falling in love with a similar formula recently for the derivative of a function in the form $g(x) = (x-a)^{n}$, whose formula is $g^{(k)}= \frac{n!(x-a)^{n-k}}{(n-k)!}$. Thanks for the catch.

Comment: Write $1+x$ as $1-(-x)$

Comment: @Physor Could you transport your comment into an answer so that the question can be marked as answered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you forgot to divide on $k!$ as you should in the taylor expansion. Where the general term should read
$$
\frac{f^{(k)}(a)}{k!}(x-a)^k
$$